# why do I need 2>&1 before grep when using a pipe

Tags: redirect, grep, pipe

when I run this command `nginx -V|grep stub`, I got purely the `nginx -V` command 's output and no hightlight text was seen.

But when I redirect stderr to stdin `nginx -V 2>&1|grep stub`, the searched text was highlightened.

I wonder why I got the difference. It seems that the grep was executed among the stderr content. Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nginx -V` output was sent to `stderr` the pipe only catches `stdout` by default.

You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so the pipe (and therefore `grep`) can see it.

Comment: why is the output sent to stderr as if nginx -V was unsuccessfully performed?

Comment: I can't say for sure but perhaps it is a misunderstanding of the general practice of sending usage output to `stderr` for invalid arguments. I believed that it was the general behaviour of things to send help/version output to `stderr` until a minute ago when I went looking for the history of that behaviour and discovered that explicitly requested help/version output generally goes to `stdout` while error usage output goes to `stderr`.